# makeCluster with parallelSVM in R takes up all Memory and swap

Tags: r, parallel-processing, machine-learning

I'm trying to train a SVM model on a large dataset(~110k training points). This is a sample of the code where I am using the parallelSVM package to parallelize the training step on a subset of the training data on my 4 core Linux machine.

```
numcore = 4
train.time = c()
for(i in 1:5)
{
    cl = makeCluster(4)
    registerDoParallel(cores=numCore)
    getDoParWorkers()
    dummy = train_train[1:10000*i,]
    begin = Sys.time()
    model.svm = parallelSVM(as.factor(target) ~ .,data =dummy,
        numberCores=detectCores(),probability = T)
    end = Sys.time() - begin
    train.time = c(train.time,end)
    stopCluster(cl)
    registerDoSEQ()
}
```

The idea of this snippet of code is to estimate the time it'll take to train the model on the entire dataset by gradually increasing the size of the dummy training set. After running the code above for 10,000 and 20,000 training samples, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aa3g.png) is the memory and swap history usage statistic from the System Monitor.After 4 runs of the for loop,both the memory and swap usage is about 95%,and I get the  following error :

> Error in summary.connection(connection) : invalid connection

Any ideas on how to manage this problem? Is there a way to deallocate the memory used by a cluster after using the stopCluster() function ?

Please take into consideration the fact that I am an absolute beginner in this field. A short explanation of the proposed solutions will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your line

```
registerDoParallel(cores=numCore)
```

creates a *new* cluster with number of nodes equal to `numCore` (which you haven't stated). This cluster is never destroyed, so with each iteration of the loop you're starting more new R processes. Since you're already creating a cluster with `cl = makeCluster(4)`, you should use

```
registerDoParallel(cl)
```

instead.

(And move the `makeCluster`, `registerDoParallel`, `stopCluster` and `registerDoSEQ` calls outside the loop.)

Comment: I defined the numCore variable equal to 4 somewhere earlier. Thanks for noticing that.I've made the appropriate edit.

Comment: I removed the loop altogether, and ran the code from `dummy = train_train[1:50000,]` to `train.time = c(train.time,end)` . The memory consumption went from ~30% to 80%. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: also, I get about 20 warning messages at the end of execution, which say `closing unused connection 22` all the way down to `closing unused connection 3` . A peer told me that these messages are to be expected and are harmless. Is this true?